# Isekai manga where the hero is sent back home after defeating the evil king, but wants to go back

Tags: story-identification, manga

It's about a hero who after defeating the evil King who transported him to the fantasy world is forcefully returned to his original world by his so called "friends" but he swore to himself that he will get back to the fantasy world to get answers and manages to do so after I think 20 years by using a girl from the evil kings bloodline (who (the kings bloodline) is hunted by his former friends (also for experiments)) as a portal and is now traveling with her.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Where and when did you read this?

Comment: Was this in full colour or mostly black & white?

Comment: Sorry but i'm not so sure i think it was a mix of both and i don't remember where and when if i knew i would have used my search history

Comment: I found it after all this time it is called *Enter The Other World Reloaded* or *Reloaded into the Other World*

Comment: Summary Taken from anime-planet: When Emperor Rustanard of the Rusclan Empire summons the Otherworldly Savior from another world to fulfill a prophecy, he doesn’t expect to find 16-year-old Sihan Seong. The emperor casts him out, only to have Sihan return with a party of six warriors to defeat the so-called “Mad Emperor” and set the Rusclan people free. Just when victory is within Sihan’s grasp, he is betrayed by his teammates and sent back to his own world. 10 years later, Sihan returns to the Terranor Continent and finds an unlikely ally in Alita, the daughter of Rustanard…

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Reloaded into the Other World**

Summary and image taken from [Anime-Planet](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/reloaded-into-the-other-world):

[image]

> When Emperor Rustanard of the Rusclan Empire summons the Otherworldly Savior from another world to fulfill a prophecy, he doesn’t expect to find 16-year-old Sihan Seong. The emperor casts him out, only to have Sihan return with a party of six warriors to defeat the so-called “Mad Emperor” and set the Rusclan people free. Just when victory is within Sihan’s grasp, he is betrayed by his teammates and sent back to his own world. 10 years later, Sihan returns to the Terranor Continent and finds an unlikely ally in Alita, the daughter of Rustanard…

Comment: Although you will need to [merge your accounts](https://stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts).

Comment: I did a merge request now we wait and hope it gets accepted

Comment: Ah, my apologies for confusing the situation.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots - MangaSearcher didn't need to merge their accounts to accept this answer,  but it was still a good thing to do, regardless. For example, now that the two accounts and their individual reputation scores have been merged, MangaSearcher has been granted the [comment everywhere](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment) privilege.